# Matlab cannot validate cluster profile

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, threadpool, pool

I'm running Matlab 2013a on Ubuntu 12.04 and when I want to validate the cluster profile ( local ) it fails with these logs:

```
 2015-01-15 22:10:05 | About to evaluate task with DistcompEvaluateFileTask
 >> 2015-01-15 22:10:05 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core
 2015-01-15 22:10:05 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core/iSetup
 2015-01-15 22:10:05 | This process will exit on any fault.
 2015-01-15 22:10:05 | This process will exit when its parent process dies.
 2015-01-15 22:10:05 | About to call decode function.
 2015-01-15 22:10:05 | In parallel.internal.decode.localSingleTask
 2015-01-15 22:10:06 | Setting the desktop client to a new client with username 
 2015-01-15 22:10:06 | About to construct the storage object using constructor "makeFileStorageObject" and location "PC{}:UNIX{/home/foo/.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/R2014a}:"
 2015-01-15 22:10:06 | Error finding the StorageLocation. This is probably 
 because the StorageLocation ("PC{}:UNIX{/home/foo/.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/R2014a}:") 
 from the decode function does not exist.
 The error thrown by the StorageConstructor was : 
 Error using distcomp.filestorage/pSetStorageLocation


 Error in distcomp.abstractstorage (line 11)
 set(obj, ...

 Error in distcomp.filestorage (line 49)
 obj.abstractstorage(storageDir, distcomp.fileserializer(obj));

 Error in makeFileStorageObject (line 31)
 storage = distcomp.filestorage(xPlatformLocation);

 Error in distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core>iSetup (line 365)
         storage = storageConstructor(runprop.StorageLocation);

 Error in distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core (line 25)
     runprop = iSetup(handlers, mdceDebugEnabled, outputWriterStack, isSyncTaskEvaluation, varargin);

 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to evaluate task with DistcompEvaluateFileTask
 [2]>> [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to evaluate task with DistcompEvaluateFileTask
 [4]>> [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to evaluate task with DistcompEvaluateFileTask
 [0]>> [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to evaluate task with DistcompEvaluateFileTask
 [1]>> [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to evaluate task with DistcompEvaluateFileTask
 [3]>> 2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core/iSetup
 2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit on any fault.
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core/iSetup
 2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core/iSetup
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit on any fault.
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit when its parent process dies.
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit on any fault.
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to initialize MPI.
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit when its parent process dies.
 2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit when its parent process dies.
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core/iSetup
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to initialize MPI.
 2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit on any fault.
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Enter distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core/iSetup
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit on any fault.
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to initialize MPI.
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit when its parent process dies.
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | This process will exit when its parent process dies.
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to initialize MPI.
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to initialize MPI.
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call mpiParallelSessionStarting.
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call mpiParallelSessionStarting.
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call mpiParallelSessionStarting.
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call mpiParallelSessionStarting.
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call mpiParallelSessionStarting.
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Finished initializing MPI.
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Finished initializing MPI.
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Finished initializing MPI.
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Finished initializing MPI.
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | Finished initializing MPI.
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call decode function.
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call decode function.
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | In parallel.internal.decode.localMpiexecTask
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | In parallel.internal.decode.localMpiexecTask
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call decode function.
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call decode function.
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | About to call decode function.
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | In parallel.internal.decode.localMpiexecTask
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | In parallel.internal.decode.localMpiexecTask
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:11 | In parallel.internal.decode.localMpiexecTask
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | Setting the desktop client to a new client with username 
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | About to construct the storage object using constructor "makeFileStorageObject" and location "PC{}:UNIX{/home/foo/.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/R2014a}:"
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | Setting the desktop client to a new client with username 
 [4]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | About to construct the storage object using constructor "makeFileStorageObject" and location "PC{}:UNIX{/home/foo/.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/R2014a}:"
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | Setting the desktop client to a new client with username 
 [0]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | About to construct the storage object using constructor "makeFileStorageObject" and location "PC{}:UNIX{/home/foo/.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/R2014a}:"
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | Setting the desktop client to a new client with username 
 [1]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | About to construct the storage object using constructor "makeFileStorageObject" and location "PC{}:UNIX{/home/foo/.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/R2014a}:"
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | Setting the desktop client to a new client with username 
 [2]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | About to construct the storage object using constructor "makeFileStorageObject" and location "PC{}:UNIX{/home/foo/.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/R2014a}:"
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | Error finding the StorageLocation. This is probably 
 [3]because the StorageLocation ("PC{}:UNIX{/home/foo/.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/R2014a}:") 
 [3]from the decode function does not exist.
 [3]The error thrown by the StorageConstructor was : 
 [3]Error using distcomp.filestorage/pSetStorageLocation
 [3]Error in distcomp.abstractstorage (line 11)
 [3]set(obj, ...
 [3]Error in distcomp.filestorage (line 49)
 [3]obj.abstractstorage(storageDir, distcomp.fileserializer(obj));
 [3]Error in makeFileStorageObject (line 31)
 [3]storage = distcomp.filestorage(xPlatformLocation);
 [3]Error in distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core>iSetup (line 365)
 [3]        storage = storageConstructor(runprop.StorageLocation);
 [3]Error in distcomp_evaluate_filetask_core (line 25)
 [3]    runprop = iSetup(handlers, mdceDebugEnabled, outputWriterStack, isSyncTaskEvaluation, varargin);
 [3]2015-01-15 22:10:12 | About to exit with code: 1
```

I don't know if it is related or not but my Ubuntu server is on a virtual machine. Any idea about how to fix this?